# c++ CreateFile function error

Tags: c++

I wanted to use function CreateFile to create a file but something is wrong and I don't know what. GetLastError() gives error 87 which is The parameter is incorrect, but I can't find which one.

Code:

```
HANDLE Create;

Create = CreateFile(
        "D:\Test.txt",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS | OPEN_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

if(Create)
{
    cout << "Ok " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << GetLastError() << endl;
}
```

Comment: On a side note: you should check the returned handle like: `if (Create != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That's not really a side note. That's crucially important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\`. So you should write

```
"D:\\Test.txt"
```

for the file name.

Do you really mean to use `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`. That grants others the right to write to your file at the same time as you. I would expect to see `0` for this parameter.

You cannot combine creation disposition flags. You have to choose one and one only. So replace:

```
CREATE_ALWAYS | OPEN_ALWAYS
```

with either one or the other. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) is clear on this point:

> This parameter must be one of the following values, which cannot be combined.

Don't name your file handle `Create`. Give it a more meaningful name that indicates that it is a handle to a file. For instance `hFile`.

On top of that your error checking is wrong. Test for success with:

```
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

Take care when reading the documentation of an API function to discover how errors are reported. In the case of `CreateFile`, a return value other than `0` does not imply success.

Comment: I changed file name to "D://Test.txt" and error checking but still it doesen't create a file

Comment: Yes. I found even more errors. I think I have them all now.

Comment: Please do check the share mode as well. Surely you don't mean `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`.

Comment: Well i want to open file as soon as created, so I thought what this one is needed. First time using this function so might be wrong.

Comment: Yes. But the share mode is not related to that desire. The share mode you have chosen allows another party to open the same file and modify it at the same time as you modify it, even while you have the file open.